# Get the value of last nested textfield in an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to get the last value in  nested textfields. All the ID and the class of the textfields are the same. Below is the html and the ajax

```
<table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="textfield"></label>
    <input name="textfield" type="text" class="digit" id="textfield" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="digit" id="textfield" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="digit" id="textfield" value="3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="digit" id="textfield" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="digit" id="textfield" value="5" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$digit = $('.digit')
alert ($digit)

});
</script>
```

here is a link to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xr3kpfrg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:last` [pseudo selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) which will target the last element given a selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $digit = $('.digit:last').val(),
    alert ($digit); //should get a 5 here    
});
```

This pseudo selector works by getting all of the elements that match your selector (in this case all elements that use the `.digit` class) and based on this set of elements, it gets the last element from the set.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xr3kpfrg/2/

**Edit**: As a piece of advice, you should have unique IDs in your page as suggested by @NightOwlPrgmr in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery's last() method.

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xr3kpfrg/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $digit = $('.digit').last().val(),
    console.log($digit);
    alert($digit);
});
```

Comment: Hanlet's answer might be more efficient.